# Search 3d points to find if any are in a row

Tags: python

I'm just doing this to try improve my skills a little, I'm trying to recreate a game I thought of years ago when I was bored in school.

Basically it's kinda like a 3d connect 4, also supposed to flip over so it'll screw up your ideas if your spacial awareness isn't great. I've tried making a very basic display in python (I know how to build things in maya, not in python, so for now I'll stick with a rubbish looking design until I get it working), and it can also lookup the points and place them in.

However, I'm stuck on actually reading these points to find any rows of 4. I know I could physically type it all out, but I'm sure there would be a much better way.For example, each corner point could go either x, y, z, xy, xz, yz, or xyz, I don't expect anyone to do the code for me, but it'd be appreciated if you could tell me a way of calculating this without typing out each possible combination (I think there's 76 in total unless I missed any)

I would have done a loop if not for the diagonals, but I have no idea how I'd go about checking these

Cheers

The code so far is here -

```
#x(width),z(depth),y(height),playernum
points=[1,4,1,1],[2,1,3,1],[4,4,1,2],[3,4,1,2],[2,4,1,2],[1,1,2,1]

for j in range(1,5):
#set indent
spaces="        "
#draw top
print spaces + "________________"

#search points on certain level
validPointsY=[]
for point in points:
    if point[2]==5-j:
        validPointsY.append( point )
#draw middle
for i in range(1,5):

    #search points on certain row
    validPointsZ=[]
    for point in validPointsY:
        if point[1]==5-i:
            validPointsZ.append( point )

    #place points in correct box
    point1=" "
    point2=" "
    point3=" "
    point4=" "
    for point in validPointsZ:
        if point[0]==1:
            point1=str(point[3])
        if point[0]==2:
            point2=str(point[3])
        if point[0]==3:
            point3=str(point[3])
        if point[0]==4:
            point4=str(point[3])

    #remove one from space
    spaces = spaces[:-1]
    print spaces + "/ "+point1+" / "+point2+" / "+point3+" / "+point4+" /"
    spaces = spaces[:-1]
    print spaces + "/___/___/___/___/"
```

Just for the record, the game is quite fun if you have nothing to do, obviously it's not gonna look great at all from this though haha

Comment: Let me point you in the direction of the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module.

Comment: Also, in terms of 3d graphics and Python, Panda3d and Blender would both work well.

Comment: I'm quite unsure how you arrive at 76.  If you have wrap-over it means that every point can be the start of a potential row of 4 in each of the possible directions (i.e. no restrictions like hitting the border).  There are 4x5x5 points (apparently, from your code).  There are not 7 directions but actually 13 (you forgot the "counter-diagonal" ones, like '4,1,1' - '3,2,1' - '2,3,1' - '1,4,1').  The total is 4x5x5x13=1300.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at itertools once I've got a few of my assignments handed in, see if I can get it working :)

And armin, it's a 4x4x4 grid (I know it looks like 5, but I've started it at 1 instead of 0), and with the example you mentioned, if I understand you right it's what I meant by the xyz direction :) But anyway, I was trying to count as in the lines as opposed to each point, so for example, the point 1,1,1 shares one line with 1,1,4 (so I'd count 1 less), and they both share a line with 1,4,4 (so I'd count 2 less), if you get what I mean :P

Comment: `itertools` is not going to help at all.  This module is a way to compress Python loops into more dense and more subtle code.  Whether it's better or worse depends on the taste.  If the problem is to find the correct algorithm, I can only recommend to use Python loops.  Re number: it makes 4x4x4x13 / 4 = 208.

Comment: Ah, sorry!  Indeed, that's 76.  I was put off track by your comment "also supposed to flip over".  I thought it meant that you'd accept something like '1,3' - '2,4' - '3,1' - '4,2' (a valid alignment too if we consider that the next value after 4 flips over to 1).

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry haha, I meant the flip is just to throw people off, because after a few games you get the hang of it and it becomes a bit too easy against other people :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't need optimizations (it is small enough), so a "naive" solution works well enough.  You can enumerate all possible alignments, starting at each possible points and going in any possible direction:

```
for x in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
  for y in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    for z in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
      # start of the alignment is given by (x, y, z).
      for dx in [-1, 0, +1]:
        for dy in [-1, 0, +1]:
          for dz in [-1, 0, +1]:
            # add (dx, dy, dz) for each successive point.
            # check that it makes a valid alignment first.
            if ((dx, dy, dz) != (0, 0, 0) and
                1 <= x + 3*dx <= 4 and
                1 <= y + 3*dy <= 4 and
                1 <= z + 3*dz <= 4):
              # that's a valid alignment.
              print (x, y, z), (x + 3*dx, y + 3*dy, z + 3*dz)
```

This prints 152 lines, i.e. 2 times 76: each alignment is found from both ends.  It should not matter.  You can replace the "print" line with a check that all 4 points have a stone from the same player.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot man, it works perfectly :D   I more or less understand how you've done it now, took a while to get my head around the if statement though haha :P  But yeah cheers, should be fairly easy to do the rest from now on :)